# Excel – Filter values with special rules for duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two locations (rooms) and a bunch of IDs
that are in a many-to-many relationship;
i.e., each ID can occur one or more times in one or both rooms. 
Here's a small example:

```
ID:       Location
1         Room_1
2         Room_2
3         Room_1
3         Room_2
4         Room_1
4         Room_1
```

I'd like to separate the IDs into two groups based on location. 
If an ID appears only in Room_1, I want it to go into Group 1. 
If an ID appears only in Room_2, I want it to go into Group 2. 
If an ID appears in more than one instance (row), like 3 and 4 above,
I want to group it into Group 2 if any of the IDs are Room 2. 
If there are multiple instances, but they're all in Room 1,
then the ID can stay in Group 1.

So in the example, I'd want IDs 1 and 4 to be in the first group,
and IDs 2 and 3 to be in the second one.

The ideal solution would be to split them into separate sheets,
but any kind of separation would be fine.

---

Here's a larger data sample:

```
ID:       Location
1         Room_1
2         Room_2
3         Room_1
3         Room_2
4         Room_1
4         Room_1
5         Room_2
6         Room_1
7         Room_2
7         Room_2
```

After grouping it should look like this:

```
Group 1:

ID:       Location
1         Room_1
4         Room_1
4         Room_1
6         Room_1

Group 2:

ID:       Location
2         Room_2
3         Room_1
3         Room_2
5         Room_2
7         Room_2
7         Room_2
```

A perhaps more straightforward way of expressing it is:

- Every ID that appears *only* in Room_1 goes into Group 1.
- Every ID that appears in Room_2 (at all) goes into Group 2.

  [image: Venn diagram]

Except also I want to retain each distinct row from the input,
even those that are identical.

Comment: Have you tried to use subtotal? Subtotal has utility on "Groub By" and "count" or "sum". Or you could simply sort on column 2 (location).

Comment: What about 'Sort'? Did you try _anything_?

Comment: @Aganju I think this is more complicated than you think. Yes I tried sort. When I sort by Location, the IDs get split up. When I sort by ID, the locations aren't sorted. I want duplicate IDs to stay together _and_ the locations to be sorted like I talked about above.

Comment: @sg4 Further looking at your data. This sort of grouping would be great in a database, like MS Access. You can have one "table", just as you've displayed it, and then perform "queries" on that one table. I can query a table, but not experienced in the few ways that Excel has tried to convince users that Excel is a database which is isn't but they've added new query features to give reason to keep using Excel. Excel is easier to manipulate data if you're not studied in database management and SQL. Look for a way that Excel "queries" a table.

Comment: Because your data-set is so small I'm looking for logic, but I have succumbed to assuming, which is bad. So, why are ID's, 1 and 4, grouped together? Solely because ID's 1-and-4 they are in room_1? And ID's 2 and 3 separated why? Could you edit your data and the question so that it's evident what goes where and why?

Comment: I'd suggest adding more data and then data below it so demonstrate how the end result looks like. A picture is worth about a thousand words.

Comment: @ejbytes Yes, I want IDs with Room_1 to be in one group and IDs with Room_2 to be in a separate group. But if one ID is in Room_1 and Room_2, I'd want it to be displayed with Room_2. Basically if any ID, however many locations it has, has a Room_2 in it, I want that ID and all its locations placed in Room_2. Should I explain more or does it make sense?

Comment: `If an ID has more than 1 location (like 3 and 4 above),` is false, ID 4 only has one location, room_1

Comment: I'll add more data to make it clearer

Comment: @sg4, several people have apparently managed to figure out what you're asking, but complex questions like this can make people's brain hurt when they try to decipher it in the abstract.  This would be much easier to understand, and might attract more answers, if you provide some real-life context.  What does all of this and the rules actually represent?  If people can visualize the actual, physical problem, they have something to hang all of this abstract stuff on.

Comment: @sg4 I think I solved the puzzle. I enjoyed this challenge actually. I think you will be pleased as to how dynamic the solution could be. I could have well created a VBa script, but using the pivot table came in handy. There are 4 Sheets/Tabs for the Workbook: 1) Table Sheet for table to be imported. 2) A copy of the table in each cell points to the Table, but in the second column is a formula. 3) A pivot table for Room_1. 4) A pivot table for Room_2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for the solution you desired, it takes 4 steps:

**STEP1**:

- Import your data to a table (**Table Tab**)
- Insert a Pivot Table (PT) on the columns, not just the current data,
  the whole way down; this will make for Dynamic Growth which can be
  "Refreshed" to the PT in the Options Menu when the PT is selected.
  Note the setup of the PT to the right of the image.

**STEP2**:

- Simply insert an = into each field to copy each cell from the "Table
  Tab".
- In the second column, insert the formula as seen in **Copy Tab** starting
  in B2:
  `=IFNA(IF(AND(LOOKUP(A2,Table!$J$3:$AZ$3)=A2,LOOKUP(A2,Table!$J$4:$AZ$4)=A2),"Room_2",Table!B2),Table!B2)`

**STEP3**:

- Insert a new sheet "Room_1", a PT wrt the "Copy Tab".
- Note the Filter for Room_1/Location.
- See the **Room_1 Tab**.

**STEP4**:

- Insert a new sheet "Room_2", a PT wrt the "Copy Tab".
- Note the Filter for Room_2/Location.
- See the **Room_2 Tab**.

[image]

**GIF image**. Click to enlarge and view each layer.

Comment: Thanks man! I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out!

Comment: @sg4 You are welcome! Glad to help out :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have really described your problem accurately,
and you’re not going to say something like,
“Oh, in my ***real*** data, I have more than two rooms.”

I’ll assume that you have “ID” in Column `A` and “Location” in Column `B`,
and everything else is available for derived values. 
(If that’s not the case, just push this out to the first unused column.) 
Assuming that you have headers (“ID” and “Location”) in Row 1,

- In cell `C2`, insert `=A2 & B2`
- In cell `D2`, insert `=ISERROR(MATCH(A2 & "Room_2", C$2:C$11, 0))`
  Replace `11` with the number of the last row where you have data.
- Select cells `C2` and `D2`,
  and drag/fill down to the last row where you have data.

`&` is Excel’s string concatenation operator. 
You could also say `CONCATENATE(A2, B2)`,
but `A2 & B2` is obviously much more concise. 
This yields values like `1Room_1`, `2Room_2`, `3Room_1`, `3Room_2`, …, etc.,
in Column `C`. 
The function `MATCH(A2 & "Room_2", C$2:C$11, 0)` (in Column `D`)
searches Column `C` for an occurrence of
the ID from this row concatenated with the string `Room_2`. 
In other words, is there a row where *this* ID is in Room 2? 
If there is one,
`MATCH` returns an index number and `ISERROR` returns FALSE. 
Otherwise, `MATCH` returns an error and `ISERROR` returns TRUE.

So Column `D` contains TRUE for every ID that appears only in Room 1,
and FALSE for any ID that appears (at least once) in Room 2:

[image: before sort]

Then sort on Column `D` in largest to smallest (descending) order, so the TRUE rows come before the FALSE rows:

[image: after sort]